# jQuery show for 5 seconds then hide

Tags: jquery, hide, message, show, timed

I'm using `.show` to display a hidden message after a successful form submit.

How to display the message for 5 seconds then hide?

Answer (score 391, accepted):

You can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) before an animation, like this:

```
$("#myElem").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

If it's not an animation, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) directly, like this:

```
$("#myElem").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#myElem").hide(); }, 5000);
```

You do the second because `.hide()` wouldn't normally be on the animation (`fx`) queue without a duration, it's just an instant effect.

Or, another option is to use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) yourself, like this:

```
$("#myElem").show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
  $(this).hide(); n();
});
```

Comment: Suggestion 2 worked perfectly with showing a checkmark icon and using fadeOut() instead of hide(). Great answer.

Comment: @wilsjd No you can't, `.delay()` will not work with `.hide()` the element will be shown then immediately hidden. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/vbfue61f/1/) this is why Nick stated "If it's not an animation, use setTimeout() directly, like this:...."

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if that used to work two years ago. Nice find though. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: I have also implemented this, but when I show msg twice within 5 seconds then it should hide prev and re-show, while it do not reset delay of first

Answer (score 19):

You can use the below effect to animate, you can change the values as per your requirements

```
$("#myElem").fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500).effect("pulsate", { times: 2 }, 800).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: $(...).fadeIn(...).animate(...).effect is not a function in JQuery 2.1.3

Comment: @DustinCharles Add jQueryUI not just jQuery. jQuery doesn't contain the effect() function
e.g. https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 7):

Just as simple as this:

```
$("#myElem").show("slow").delay(5000).hide("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

To show error message of 5 sec using ajax that is save in session in laravel 8

```php
<div id="error">
    @php
        $error = Session::get('message');
        echo $error;
    @endphp
</div>
<script>
    $("#error").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#error").hide();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```