# How to show div for 10 seconds and then hide it

Tags: jquery

I have div block which comes on a mouseover of another div.

div1 img // mouse over shows div2.

I want to show div2 for 10 seconds and then hide it , can you please tell me how to achive this

Thanks

Comment: Post a sample of HTML to get the best answer.  There could be event-order issues if the divs are nested.

Comment: @silkster , next time i will definetly do that. I got the answer , thanks very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery show for 5 seconds then hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428766/jquery-show-for-5-seconds-then-hide)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$("#div1").mouseenter(function() {
    var $div2 = $("#div2");
    if ($div2.is(":visible")) { return; }
    $div2.show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $div2.hide();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Another way to go:

```
$("#div1").mouseenter(function() {
    var $div2 = $("#div2");
    if ($div2.data("active")) { return; }
    $div2.show().data("active", true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $div2.hide().data("active", false);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: @sime one more thing , if it is visible it should hide after 10 seconds..we shouldn't return there right. IF it is visible we hve to set t.he setTimout function on that

Comment: @gov Is the #div2 hidden in the beginning?

Comment: @sime , the div2 will be hidden onload of the page.

Comment: @gov When you hover #div1 for the first time, #div2 will be hidden, and the function will not return. Instead the #div2 will be shown and the timeout will be set. Now, if you hover again, and #div2 is still visible (the 10 seconds haven't passed yet), the function will return - because we don't want to set yet another timeout.

Comment: +1 I think this is the only answer that safeguards against multiple timeouts being set.

Answer (score 20):

Use jQuery's delay(n); method 
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
 $(function() {
      $("#div1 img").hover(function(){
        $("#div2").show().delay( 10000 ).hide(0);
      });
    });
```

Comment: There are two mistakes in your code: 1. the hover() method, when supplied with only one function argument, executes that function on both mouseenter **and mouseleave**, which is clearly not what the OP wants, 2. the delay() method does only work with animations and not with show() or hide() (Note: if you supply an argument to show() or hide(), it becomes an animation and then it does work). Your code `show().delay(10000).hide()` will hide the element **immediately** and not after 10 seconds.

Comment: See [answer by @user113716](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128518/616644) for example of correct usage.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is the only good one here.

I'm leaving an answer because most of the others fail for various reasons.

If you want to use `.delay()`, the item delayed needs to be part of the queue. The `.hide()` method is not. But if you give `.hide()` a duration, it is.

So you can do this:

```
var $div2 = $('#div2');

$('#div1').mouseenter(function() {
    $div2.show().delay( 10000 ).hide( 0 );
});
```

The `0` duration makes `.hide()` part of the queue. You don't want to use `.hover()` because it will fire once for `mouseenter` and once for `mouseleave`. This is not what was wanted.

Some of the answers using `setTimeout()` fail because if there are several `mouseenter` events, then several `setTimeout()` calls are made. The accepted answer gets around this.

Comment: I like this one more than the accepted answer if one is using jQuery. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

as part of the mouseover function:

```
setTimeout(function(d){
  item.hide();
}, 10000);
```

This assumes `var item` is the jquery object of the div you want to hide. The parameter `10000` is the delay in milliseconds. 10s * 1000ms/1s = 10000ms

Comment: I voted for this one because even though this question is tagged as [jquery] it does not ask for a jQuery solution specifically.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $("div1 img").hover(
        function() { //mouse over show div
            $("div2").show(); //.delay(10000).fadeOut();
        },
        function() { // mouse out, start timer to hide
            //$("div2").delay(10000).fadeOut();
        }
    );    
});
```

Comment: you mean setTimeout? setInterval will repeat every 10s unless cancelled.

Comment: @ hunter will this hide div 2 after 10 seconds?

Comment: i want to show div2 for 10 seconds , after 10 seconds it should fadeout

Comment: to make things simeple , if div2 is present more than 10 seconds on screen , it should fade out..

Answer (score 2):

```
var $div2 = $('#div2');


$('#div1').mouseover( function(){
  $div2.show();

  setTimeout( function(){
    $div2.hide();
  }, 1000*10);

});
```