# .show("fast") not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, show

I have got a script here that animates a div changing height, then after a label should appear. Under that I have return false so the next page doesn't load.

It works when it is like this

```
$("label#error-username_r").show();
return false;
```

However when I set the duration it ignores it, and ignores the return false and loads the next page like this:

```
$("label#error-username_r").show("fast");
return false;
```

Here is all of the code:

```
        $("div#cover").animate
            ({
                height: window.innerHeight*0.8
                }, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:"backEaseInOut"}
            );
        $("div#cover-bottom").animate
            ({
                height: window.innerHeight*0.2
                }, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:"backEaseInOut"}
            );
        $("label#error-username_r").show();
        return false;
```

Comment: FYI, there is no need to put the tag name in front of the id.  That just slows down selector engines.  `"label#error-username_r"` can just be `"#error-username_r"` and so on.

Comment: There must be something in your code that you aren't showing us because `.show("fast")` works just fine when used properly.  You can see it work here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/V6DYz/

Comment: It was working fine until I added the ease plugin from the jQuery website. When I remove the ease settings in my .animate it works fine again?

Comment: could be the conflicts with native jquery code when introducing 3rd jquery plugin. Perhaps try to reorder your jquery code, say include them before `</body>`. It's not always necessary to have them within the header.

Comment: @PeterStuart - To close off this question, you should post an answer yourself that explains that it was some sort of error/conflict with a jQuery easing plug-in.  Then give your own answer the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda hard to dig out the real problem without HTML. And I don't think it's because `show("fast")` failed here. It's gotta be some other code that behaved incorrectly.

You might want to try the duration as the passing parameter, like this

```
("#error-username_r").show(1000);
```

But I doubt that would really solve your problem either, as I said earlier, the error most likely is in somewhere else of your code.

Anyway, I'd suggest you try [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or any other web development tools to inspect the js errors and see what the error messages are.

Comment: Hi there.  I already use firebug.  I have actually came accross various errors now. Firebug is shotting out errors with this easing plugin so I'm going to remove it and find an alternative.  Thanks :)

Comment: I've added a comment under your question. I was suggesting that you could try re-organize your jquery code. See if you could solve it by not removing easing plugin. Worth a try.

Comment: I had the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428766/jquery-show-for-5-seconds-then-hide helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed similar behavior myself on occasion.  I started putting my values in as:

```
$("#error-username_r").show(200);
```

This always works for me.

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem.  Should have been a comment, not an answer.