# Why do jQuery show() parameters not delay before calling the `complete` function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The [jQuery API documentation for `show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) states that as of jQuery 1.4.3, one can call `.show()` like so:

```
.show( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

With the arguments being:

> - `duration` (default: 400): A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
> - `easing` (default: swing): A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
> - `complete`: A function to call once the animation is complete.

I don't need easing, so I just call this version:

```
.show( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

I have one function which is supposed to show a div, wait 5 seconds, then fade out over 500ms.

I have tried this:

```
  $('#some_div').show( {
      duration: 5000,
      complete: function() { fadeOutHelper(500); }
  } );
```

And this:

```
$('#some_div').show(5000, function() { fadeOutHelper(500); } );
```

And in neither case will `show()` actually wait 5000ms before calling the helper function.

I found a work-around on StackOverflow using `setTimeout()`: [jQuery show for 5 seconds then hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428766/jquery-show-for-5-seconds-the-hide)

```
$('#some_div').show();
setTimeout(function() { fadeOutHelper(500); }, 5000);
```

Although I have a work-around, I would like to understand how I am misunderstanding some very simple function arguments in the jQuery `show()` docs.

Comment: What is `fadeOutHelper`?

Comment: It's not delay(), the duration is the time it takes to show something, not a waiting period before you run some random function, even if it can be somewhat used as such?

Comment: Where does is state in the documentation that it will delay the action by the duration? Duration is to specify the period over which you want the show method to execute, not a delay. Documentation states: `Duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.`

Comment: Francois, will you post that as an answer?  The solution is that I misunderstood the "delay" parameter in show(), since show is either on or off, a delay means nothing.  (Why do they include it, then?  It seems to do nothing.)

Comment: There is no delay parameter. There is a duration parameter. Showing an element can be animated.

Comment: @JD: `Why do they include it, then?` the duration is the time `show()` will take to execute, causing a fade-in effect to complete over the specified period of time. If you want a 5 second delay after show then your `setTimeout` solution should be OK. You can also look into [**delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have one function which is supposed to show a div, wait 5 seconds, then fade out over 500ms.

Do you want to show a div over a period of 5 seconds, or show a div instantly and then wait 5 seconds for a callback? If it's the former, the second try will work just fine, except that you've got an extra `}` you need to remove. Use some extra white space and it's obvious:

```
$('#some_div').show(5000, function() {
    fadeOutHelper(500);
}}); // oh noes, synax error
```

If it's the latter then the "workaround" you cite is the *correct* way to implement what you want. **`setTimeout` is not a hack.** There is nothing "workaround-ish" about this:

```
$('#flash_helper').show();
setTimeout(function() { fadeOutHelper(500); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Bade inline edit on my part.  The extra } is not present in my code.  What do you mean by "show a div over a period of 5 seconds"?  Are you referring to fadeIn()?

Comment: By "show a div over a period of 5 seconds" I mean exactly what the API docs mean with the `duration` parameter: "How long the animation will run."

Comment: Since show() provides no animation (unlike fadeIn and fadeOut), this means the parameter is pointless, does it not?

Comment: You're wrong, that's all there is to it. `show()` **does** provide animation.

Comment: +1 for explaining that `setTimeout` as a viable solution and not a hack.