# How to implement simple confirmation message that disappears after some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a simple confirmation message of `successfully logging out` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428766/jquery-show-for-5-seconds-then-hide) but I am not sure how to proceed.

This message is going to appear for 5 seconds, after the user clicks the logout button (which simply does the log out and **redirects to the home page**). 
This confirmation message, along with the logout button is located at the header.

I have the text wrapped in a div, with id="confirmation".
The `onClick` event on a link calls the `informUser` function which does this:

```
$("#confirmation").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#myElem").hide(); }, 5000);
```

The css of the div wrapper is this:

```
#confirmation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 45%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Now, I needed to hide this element, I tried with `visibility: hidden;` but the element never showed up.
I tried hiding it using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#confirmation").hide("slow"); });
```

and the element showed up for less than a second and then disappeared (due to `document.ready` being loaded again).

Comment: Why you want to reinvent the wheel? My suggestion: use http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ instead.

Comment: Did you see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683363/jquery-autohide-element-after-5-seconds

Comment: @Arius I am with you on this, but I am not allowed to use other frameworks

Comment: @Chris - even MIT licensed like this one? Quite weird requirement from client :)

Comment: @Arius Unfortunately it's a stupid request by the teacher at the university. :(

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing pages (when you redirect to the home page), the javascript that handles an event on the logout button won't do anything to show and hide the message on the home page. Instead, I would try setting a cookie with a somewhat short life span, and letting a separate script on the home page handle the displaying of the message if that cookie is set.

You can see a basic overview of cookies here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a typo in the post, but I can't leave comments yet, so here's my answer (just in case).

```
$("#confirmation").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#myElem").hide(); }, 5000);
```

should be

```
$("#confirmation").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#confirmation").hide(); }, 5000);
```