# Blocking 'show then hide' after n seconds with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform something pretty easy at first glance but I can not do it.
I have a button, and two hidden div. When the button is pushed, I want the first div to show and after n seconds, to hide and then the second div show.

html :

```
<button id="button">
  push
</button>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
  firstDiv
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
  secondDiv
</div>
```

The whole code, with the JS is here : https://jsfiddle.net/439xbfe5/

I have already checked the answers here : [jQuery show for 5 seconds then hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428766/jquery-show-for-5-seconds-then-hide)

The problem for this code is #div2 shows up before #div1 disapears :

```
$("#button").click(()=>{

  var timeLimit = 5000;
  $("#div1").show().delay(timeLimit).fadeOut();
  $("#div2").show();
  
});
```

Same problem here :

```
$("#button").click(()=>{

  var timeLimit = 5000;
  $("#div1").show();
  setTimeout(function() { $("#div1").hide(); }, timeLimit );
  $("#div2").show();
  
});
```

I also tried to create a blocking sleep function like :

```
function sleep(ms){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while(true){ 
    if(new Date().getTime()-start>ms){
        return; 
     }
  }
}

$("#button").click(()=>{

  var timeLimit = 5000;
  $("#div1").show();
  sleep(timeLimit);
  $("#div2").show();
});
```

But this doesnt work at all.

Also, showing #div2 is just an illustration of my problem. **Actually, I dont need to 'compilate' show then hide but #div1 is more like a transition step between before and after the button is pushed.** I hope you understood my problem (sorry for my english).

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`complete` callback](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function to do something "after" a jquery animation is done.

```js
$("#button").click(()=>{

  var timeLimit = 5000;
  $("#div1").show().delay(timeLimit).fadeOut(function(){
    $("#div2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">
  push
</button>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
  firstDiv
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
  secondDiv
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works pretty well. The problem is that I can't use a callback function because the actual code is pretty different. To illustrate, instead of button click event, I have a function transition() doing this show then hide animation. This function is called several times, that is why I can not use complete callback function.