# Showing an element for 3 seconds then remove it and show another element - jQuery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a small function to show some data to an user that looks like this.

```
function message(msg) {
    
  var html = '<div class="reply" style="display: flex;"><div class="avtar-img"><img class="ChatItem-avatarImage" id="ct_img" src="'+ui_obj.logo+'"></div><p id="Log">'+
  msg.msg_text +
  '</p>'+
  '<span class="chat-time">'+ formatAMPM(new Date) + '</span></div>';
  return html;
}
```

Then I have this image

```
<img src="loading.gif" class="float-left">
```

What I want to achieve is that the loading image is shown for 3 seconds and then to hide it and show the other content of the function.

The whole thing has to happen within the message function itself.

I have tried to delay the execution of the code, creating another function within the message function and using `setTimeout(function, 3000)` to delay it, but somehow can't achieve that.

So, in short, what I am trying to achieve is:

- show loading.gif for 3 seconds and hide it
- show the content of the message function
- and everything must happen within the message function

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery show for 5 seconds then hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428766/jquery-show-for-5-seconds-then-hide)

Comment: I was looking at that but didn't help too much

Comment: Is necessary to `return` from function you can put your code inside `setTimeout` and add the generated html to some divs inside callback of it or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24929146/10606400) is another solution .